# Регистрация и авторизация в мобильном приложении, подходит ли для этого RESTfull

Tags: php, android, oauth

Как правильно реализовать регистрацию и авторизацию в мобильном приложении, подходит ли для этого RESTful веб приложение, какой протокол для этого лучше использовать и в каком виде передавать пароль с мобильного приложения на сервер. Какие бест практисы есть для данной цели.

Интересно с точки зрения бэк-энда, подходит ли для этой цели Slim?

Comment: Лучше ИМХО будет использовать OAuth2. Это немного ортогонально RESTful. Но, если у Вас приложение будет авторизовываться на сервере, (а в последствии появится несколько приложений), то OAuth самое то. Тем более, под большинство фреймворков (и бековых, и фронтовых, и мобильных) уже есть готовые модули. Slim подойдет.